# Changing text to True or False

Tags: android

I have a Boolean which returns True or False depending on a the method result.

I want to make a large text, which every time writes TRUE or FALSE depending on that Boolean.

How do I do that?
It's a burst camera.

The thing is, I'm using a camera as a Button, every time someone touches the camera it returns FALSE, and every time the camera is taking pictures without anyone setting it to dark, it returns TRUE.

When FALSE happens, the camera goes to another Activity.
The TRUE and FALSE thing is working just fine, but I can only check it on my log.

I just want a Button which instead writes a text in the app UI.

```
public static boolean ImagemEscura(Bitmap img)
    {
        float totalpixel = img.getWidth() * img.getHeight();
        float totalpixelescuro = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++)
            {
                int cor = img.getPixel(x, y);

                if(SomaRGB(cor) > 90)
                {
                    totalpixelescuro++;
                }
            }
        }

        return totalpixelescuro/totalpixel > 0.75f;
    }

    public static int SomaRGB(int cor)
    {
        return getRed(cor) + getGreen(cor) + getBlue(cor);
    }

    public static int getRed(int argb)
    {
        return argb >> 16 & 0xFF;
    }

    public static int getGreen(int argb)
    {
        return argb >> 8 & 0xFF;
    }

    public static int getBlue(int argb)
    {
        return argb & 0xFF;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the code you wrote to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

If the function returns a boolean value, then check if the returned value is `true` or `false`. Then set your `TextView` accordingly.

You can just add this to your code

```
Boolean result=your_class.ImagemEscura(your_bitmap);
if(result)
    your_textview.setText("TRUE");
else
    your_textview.setText("FALSE");
```

Comment: That you will have to decide..its really hard to tell that without knowing what you are trying to achieve..

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one line:

```
mYourTextView.setText(String.valueOf(ImagemEscura(bitmap)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in one line:

```
your_textview.setText(your_class.ImagemEscura(your_bitmap) ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
```